# Can you copy large data files on an IPhone 4? Files > 1GB?

Tags: iphone

Can you copy large data files on an IPhone 4? Files > 1GB?

Answer (score 3):

[Using your iPod as a storage drive](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1478?viewlocale=en_US)

> If you use your iPod as a disk with a Windows PC, keep in mind that the FAT32 file system can only accommodate files that are smaller than 4 gigabytes. No matter how much free space there is on your iPod, you can't copy files that are larger than that.

While that note is for '`iPod`' it probably applies to '`iPhone`' as well.
<sup>Meaning, I don't expect iPhone to use NFTS or ext* formats</sup>.

With an iPod, you have the option to [Format to NTFS](http://www.ehow.com/how_6200551_format-ipod-ntfs.html);
Which does not make sense with iPhone -- it would no longer be a phone I guess.

Now, if you were to partition the iPhone space in some way to 'carve' out a new NTFS, ext2/3/4 partition on it, *that* might let you write larger files -- of course, you'd need to carve out more that your target files size in the first place.

Finally, **if you just want to carry your large file on the iPhone** (not play it there),
you could [**split**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/man1/split.1.html) the file into smaller chunks ([GNOME split](http://www.gnome-split.org/) is one example, there are many tools for this).